# Correct php for returning mySQL query as string

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using the following code with an AJAX request to find the "status" of someone in my "user" table who matches a specific "userid" sent with the AJAX request. I simply need the the status returned as a one word string (it is either "ON" or "OFF"). After hacking around I have got this code to work, but would like to know are there any glaring problems, especially regarding deprecations that will make this code invalid any time soon? Thanks for any improvement that can be suggested.

```
<?php
$server = "myserver.com";
$username = "someuser";
$password = "somepassword";
$database = "somedatabase";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$name=$_POST['p'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM user WHERE userid LIKE '$name'");

$result=mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo implode(" ",$result);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and removed entirely in PHP 7) and you shoud [stop using them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) if you can. You should choose another API, like `mysqli_*` or PDO instead - see [choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Also, StackOverflow isn't a code-review service. If it's working, it belongs on another network, perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Qirel Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a database to communicate PDO or MySQLi

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

This code is problematic due to MySQL injection.

```
$name=$_POST['p'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

First: Use a framework with a built in ORM.
Don't write yourself code that connects to the database, try for example to post this string `'; DROP table user` and have fun. This kind of attacks are old and known as [sqlinjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).